# How to automatically register widgets on new blog?

Tags: multisite, widgets

Is there a way to automatically register widgets when a new site is registered with a multi site setup? E.g. inside `wpmu_new_blog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your themes `functions.php` file you can check wether or not it get's installed for the first time on that blog. This can be done by using an option. An option can be set to flag that it's installing.

This option that signals that an install is immanent can be used in a hook of the `init` jointcut so to flag for automatic widget registration. Widgets can be registerd with [wp_set_sidebars_widgets()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/widgets.php#L1090). After that's done, kill the flag.

Keep in mind that switching themes kills the widgets configuration. So this is for first-time use only.

A full working example on how to register widgets on theme activation can be found in the [Semiologic Reloaded Theme](http://www.semiologic.com/software/sem-reloaded/). It's available for download, feel free to suit yourself.

Comment: @hakre - Your hyperlink is broken.

Comment: @hakre - Also, maybe give a working example? If so, you'll answer less questions but they will be more helpful and thus more people will rate your answers highly. Lots of questions answered with only a little direction provided is less useful than fewer questions answered but answered well. When you answer every question with short answers it sometimes causes others to think "Why bother answering, @hakre already has?", at least that's how I sometimes feel.

Comment: Okay, I see, will take some care on that.

Comment: Actually I ended up just modifying the sidebar.php to provide the correct default widgets if no dynamic_sizebar was set. This was good enough for me, but thanks for your more generic solution.

Comment: Oh okay, it was not clear to me that this would be already fitting for you.

Comment: I looked a bit into this and got a trouble. You wouldn't know how I should calculate the multi_number for the widget I'm adding?

Comment: hakre, I found a solution. I check for get_options('widget_<widget name>'). If it's not present, I do the wp_set_sidebars_widgets. Seems to work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Much easier. There's [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) function already present. Just consult the codex.

Comment: Kaiser: Not really the same thing, is it? The former registers the widget. All you're doing it is calling it. What if I have someone that doesn't want the widget anymore and has no idea how to edit the_widget code?