# Placing a widget with $wpdb query

Tags: widgets, mysql, query, wpdb

I'm getting the feeling that adding Widgets via MySQL query is not as simple as I thought. I was under the impression all data is stored in the `options` table, but it seems like I was wrong.

Any idea how to place a widget via $wpdb? What data should be written down? And where?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing widgets via a MySQL or something MySQL abstracted via the global variable `$wpdb` that is an instance of the WPDB class is *not* trivial.

That's not because MySQL is something complicated or because `$wpdb` is useless at all but this has do something with the way the widget configuration is stored inside the mysql database options tables.

But there is always a work around. The nature of the widget configuration is stored inside the mysql database options tables. Just read the widgets configuration out of the option ([get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)), edit it as you wish (use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to inspect how that array is used) and then store it back into mysql via [update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option).

That done you should be able to edit this "via mysql" (e.g. in the database) while making the settings of your wish.

This is quite a quick answer but it probably solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I actually already started doing just the debugging you suggested. Works pretty slow so far. Seems like the widget metadata is somewhat dynamic. Still testing for results, though.

Comment: @konzepz: It's an array that contains multiple widget entries. var_dump() is the best you can get so far I'm aware of. So true, it's slow, but just for a hint: The format of that data is not documented anywhere. Welcome to wordpress :). Install xdebug (!) to have this better displayed.

Comment: Interesting post: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-widget-system

Comment: @konzepz: yes, it pretty well describes the basic facts and is explaining the structure of the array. good catch, thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: Actually, it looks pretty useful, since it's describing the use for wp_get_sidebars_widgets and wp_set_sidebars_widgets commands!

Comment: Another WP Answers post regarding these features: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/986/how-to-automatically-register-widgets-on-new-blog